# JMS message selector and JMSCorrelationID with UUID as value

Tags: java, jms

So I am having a hard time reading a JMS message with the message melector using `JMSCorrelationID` as key. I can read the message without using a selector though.

When I set the `JMSCorrelationID` I encode it with base64 like this:

```java
UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("9e763b6f-d168-4661-93db-99903eb9c865");
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
bb.putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits());
bb.putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
byte[] bytes = bb.array();
msg.setJMSCorrelationID(new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes)));
```

When reading the message again (without a message selector), I discovered that I had to read the `JMSCorrelationID` with `getJMSCorrelationIDAsBytes()` and then reverse the process to get the UUID. Other than that, reading the message reading the message went fine.

But how can I target the message with a message selector?

I have tried all of the following:

```java
consumer = queueSession.createConsumer(replyQueue, "JMSCorrelationID='" + bytes + "'");
consumer = queueSession.createConsumer(replyQueue, "JMSCorrelationID='" + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes)) + "'");
consumer = queueSession.createConsumer(replyQueue, "JMSCorrelationID='ID:" + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes)) + "'");
```

But I keep getting empty results!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you just set the correlation ID directly without using UUID or byte[] (e.g. `msg.setJMSCorrelationID("9e763b6f-d168-4661-93db-99903eb9c865"`)? Your code seems overly complex.

Comment: I tried that, and when reading the message, only 24 of the 36 characters remained

Comment: What JMS broker are you using? There is nothing in the JMS specification limiting the size of `JMSCorrelationID`.

Comment: That would be IBM's MQ I assume and according to this https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/8.5.5?topic=piwm-mapping-message-header-fields-properties-from-websphere-mq-format#rjc0007___note1 , it states the length of the correlationId

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this works on ActiveMQ Artemis:

```java
ConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://0");
try (JMSContext context = cf.createContext()) {
   UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("9e763b6f-d168-4661-93db-99903eb9c865");
   ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
   bb.putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits());
   bb.putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
   byte[] bytes = bb.array();

   Message msg = context.createMessage();
   String cid = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes));
   msg.setJMSCorrelationID(cid);

   Queue queue = context.createQueue("foo");
   context.createProducer().send(queue, msg);
   msg = context.createConsumer(queue, "JMSCorrelationID='" + cid + "'").receive(1000);
   org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(msg);
}
```

This is essentially equivalent to what you're doing so I'm not sure why it's not working for you with IBM MQ.